# Why did the community close this question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

This question has been closed as duplicate by community despite I updated the question clarifying why it wasn't duplicate: [Why did Lucas choose to keep memory of R2-D2?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84628/why-did-lucas-choose-to-keep-memory-of-r2-d2)

Unlike the other question, I asked from out-of-universe perspective. Also, none of the answers on the other question answers my question.

How can my question be duplicate?

Comment: Claiming that a question isn't a duplicate doesn't make it not a duplicate.  A valid out-of-universe reason may be that Lucas decided it for in-universe reasons; therefore the in-universe answer is also the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

The other question does not ask for in-universe answers only -- it makes no mention at all of whether answers should be in-universe or real-world. Therefore, any valid answer to your question would also be a valid answer to the other question, and should be used to answer that question. The fact that there are no such answers doesn't prevent this from being a duplicate -- it may just mean that there is in fact no real-world evidence to answer your question.